# How to use Poetry when developing a package?

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I am exploring the use of `Poetry` for packaging my Python's applications.

I started using  `Poetry` on an already existing project. The structure is like this :

```
├─ bin
|  └─ main.py
├─ docs
├─ data
├─ src
│  └─ packagename
│     ├─ __init__.py
│     └─ ...
├─ tests
│  └─ ...
└─ pyproject.toml
```

I had a `virtualenv` already set up. So I executed the following commands to `Poetry`:

```
poetry init (inside the package directory)
poetry add *package lists*
```

I checked `Poetry` is recognizing the `virtualenv` with the command :

```
poetry env info
```

and this gave the expected result.

So now, I would like to test my package i.e. run the `main.py` script which does (among other things):

```
import packagename
```

To achieve this, I executed :

```
poetry install
poetry run bin\main.py
```

but the `poetry run` command throws a  `ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'packagename'`. What am I not understanding/doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the whole error message for the `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: I updated the question. It simply states that there is no module named 'packagename'

Comment: Do you mind showing the `pyproject.toml`? At least we need to know if the project name and top level package name are somewhat conventional, otherwise _poetry_ can not pick it up automatically. If for whatever reason the package name is not a normalized version of the project name, then you can always use the `include` setting of `pyproject.toml`.